# HackerRank | Roads and Libraries - Code Optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, graph

Major Edit: I wish people threw in a comment regarding what they are expecting instead of downvoting this question. I am quite appreciative of constructive feedback. I know it is only 3 people out of 100 who have downvoted, but it still affects the poster's confidence and makes this forum unhelpful.

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/torque-and-development/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=graphs) Hackerank problem and some of my test cases are failing stating that the final answer is wrong. After going over a previous S.O [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604159/hackerrank-roads-and-libraries-getting-wrong-answer-in-some-test-cases) for the same problem, my understanding is that HackerRank says that the answer is wrong if the code doesn't execute within the memory and time limit. I'd like to know how I can further optimize my code to reduce the run time and space complexity

```
def roadsAndLibraries(n, c_lib, c_road, cities):
    
    # The arguments to the function above are number of nodes (n), cost of a library and road (c_lib, c_road) and cities connected by an edge (cities)
    graph = {}
    count = 0
    cc = []
    visited = set()
    
    
    #Adding all edges to create an Adjacency List using a dictionary
    for source,dest in cities:
        graph[source] = graph.get(source,[])+[dest]
        graph[dest] = graph.get(dest, []) + [source]
    #There is a weird condition in Hackerrank wherein the number of nodes (n) in the input can be greater than the max(cities). In that case, one needs to consider the additional nodes as an independent graph in a forest.
    if max(graph, key = int)<n:
        for i in range(max(graph, key = int)+1,n+1):
            graph[i]=[]
            
            
    # Generic Depth First Search         
    def depth_first_search(graph, visited, node, temp):
        if node not in visited:
            visited.add(node)
            temp.add(node)
            
            if node in graph:
                
                for neighbor in graph[node]:
                    
                    depth_first_search(graph, visited, neighbor, temp)
        return temp
    
        
    #Identify Connected Components using a Depth First Search.
    #These Connected Components will subsequentially used to calculate the cost    
    def connected_components(graph, visited):
        
        for key in graph:
            #print("Key = ", key)
            if key not in visited:
                temp = set()
                cc.append(depth_first_search(graph, visited, key, temp))
        return cc
    connected_components(graph, visited)
    
    
    #Return final cost over here
    cost = 0
                
    if c_road>c_lib:
        return n*c_lib
    else:
        for each in cc:
            cost += c_lib + (len(each)-1)*c_road
        return cost
```

Comment: The output information of each failed test case on HackerRank explicitly tells you whether it fails due to "Wrong answer" or "Time limit exceeded". You should check that rather than guessing the cause of failure. As a side remark, "Time limit exceeded" can be caused by both non-terminating and inefficient algorithm implementations.

Comment: Well my implementation passes the base test cases. Also the discussion sections are filled with people say that an unoptimized algorithm /unsuitable variable types returns a wrong answer instead of timeout.

Comment: By unsuitable variable types I mean using an int instead of long. I am not sure how to specify it here though.

Comment: "Time limit exceeded" means your program does not terminate within the time limit (10s for Python 2 / Python 3), regardless of whether it is correct or not. "Wrong answer" means your program terminates with an exception or without the expected answer in standard output. You can view that information for every test case that your submission went through, not only the base test cases.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Consider tagging [tag:programming-challenge]. Most of those contain test cases carefully crafted to exceed a reasonable time limit unless using a decent [tag:algorithm] - improving how it is coded is a secondary concern.

Comment: Thank you @greybeard

Comment: What in that other question makes you think that "HackerRank says that the answer is wrong if the code doesn't execute within the time limit"?

Comment: I guess I was wrong. It was the memory and time limit that was affecting my answer. I will update the question accordingly @superbrain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hackerank already told you, your solution is *wrong* (failing 7 out of 13 test cases). Which should make your question off-topic, not sure how to judge your pretending that they say that incorrectly.

For example, you fail `roadsAndLibraries(3, 1, 1, [[2, 3]])` by returning `2` instead of `3`. What you call "weird" is just unconnected cities. And it can happen for small-numbered cities as well. In my example, it's city 1 that's unconnected. Which you don't handle because you assume that it's always the largest-numbered cities that are unconnected.

If you simply start with `graph = {i: [] for i in range(1, n+1)}`, you succeed. Then you also don't need your own half-way special treatment for the "weird" unconnected cities.

Also, use `append` to grow the lists so you have linear instead of quadratic runtime.

```
    for source,dest in cities:
        graph[source].append(dest)
        graph[dest].append(source)
```

Alternatively, remove your half-way special treatment and add `(n - len(visited)) * c_lib` to the return value at the end, in order to put libraries in the not-visited (because unconnected) cities.

Or as yet another alternative fix, you could fix your half-way special treatment to fill in *all* unconnected cities at that point:

```
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        graph[i] = graph.get(i, [])
```

But I'd say *that* would be weird :-). It's simpler to just initialize all with an empty list at the start, *before* building the graph from the edges. And that's also better because it allows those simple `append`s.

#### Improved solution

Same basic idea, of course, placing one library in each connected component, unless libraries don't cost more than roads:

```
def roadsAndLibraries(n, c_lib, c_road, cities):
    if c_lib <= c_road:
        return n * c_lib

    graph = {u: [] for u in range(1, n+1)}
    for u, v in cities:
        graph[u].append(v)
        graph[v].append(u)
    
    def delete(u):
        for v in graph.pop(u, []):
            delete(v)

    connected_components = 0
    for u in range(1, n+1):
        if u in graph:
            connected_components += 1
            delete(u)
    
    return connected_components * c_lib + (n - connected_components) * c_road
```

Note:

- I handle `c_lib <= c_road` (and not just `<`) right at the start. No need to get to work on the graph at all if we're going to ignore that whole work anyway.
- I just count the connected components, don't keep track of each component's cities. In the end we just cover `connected_components` cities with libraries and the remaining `n - connected_components` with roads. Simple formula.
- The roads are bidirectional and the problem calls the connected cities "u" and "v", not "source" and "dest". So both for consistency with the problem and for not implying a direction, I used `u` and `v` as well (ok ok, I also like short standard names for brevity).
- If I build the graph, I can tear it down. No need for an extra `visited`.
- No need to pass `graph` through the `delete` calls as argument. (And in yours, neither your `depth_first_search` nor your `connected_components` would've needed `graph` and `visited` as parameters).

Comment: Thank you. Here is why I initially thought it was a glitch in Hackerank and not my fault - "My logic was totally correct the thing where I wasn't able to guess what was happening is that HACKERRANK handles OutOfMemoryException badly, they show wrong answer instead of showing that exception". I found this on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604159/hackerrank-roads-and-libraries-getting-wrong-answer-in-some-test-cases) and also got this vibe in the discussions board.

Comment: @desert_ranger Well that other person had an OutOfMemoryException, clearly from their adjacency matrix (of size n\*n). You had nothing like that.

Comment: Agreed. My bad :-)

Comment: `graph[i] = graph.get(i, [])` could be replaced with `graph.setdefault(i, [])`. The graph initialization could use `graph = collections.defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: @GZ0 Yeah, I just did it that way for consistency with their other `get`s. I could've suggested a few more improvements, but the main issue was resolved and it was already late at night :-). Plus that was my least favorite fix anyway, the one I called "weird", and I didn't really care about making something better that can't be good anyway. Oh well... I added an improved solution now with some notes.

Comment: Hmm, I'm quite curious how someone voted "This answer is not useful" after it pointed out that the solution was indeed wrong, what was wrong, how to fix it, pointed out the quadratic runtime and how to fix it, and had already been accepted and upvoted two or three times. How does one justify declaring that "not useful"?